# Pyspark list column is coming up as key-val pair in json document

Tags: python, json, list, pyspark

I have a use case to groupBy on a set of columns and use collect_list(col):

```
df.groupBy("col1","col2","col3").agg(collect_set(col("col4")))
```

when I do this, the schema of df is coming up as below:

```
root
 |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col4: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- *element*: string (containsNull = true)
```

When an underlying job pickup this file(which I wrote into S3 in parquet format) and converts it into json(it's a java program), col4 values are coming up like this:

```
  "col4": [
      {
        "element": "val1"
      },
      {
        "element": "val2"
      },
      {
        "element": "val3
      }     
    ]
```

Any idea why this is coming as a key:val pair here eventhough I had collected into a list?
What is the significance of 'element' here?
How to effectievly use Structtype fields in pyspark?

Comment: You should look at the java program that converts it to JSON.

Comment: @blackbishop, but in pyspark schema itself I am seeing the "element" when I do a printSchema. Does pypspark has no ListType?

Comment: This is just how Spark prints the schema, to say that the array contains elements of type string. Your pyspark code is correct, you get an array of string not array of struct. so it must be something wrong with the java code.